# Add image on HTMLBody from Messaging.SingleEmailMessage

Tags: apex, url, images, emailmessage

I'm putting an image from my salesforce org inside an HTMLBody FROM Messagin.SingleEmailMessage ('c.instance' is for my org instance. documentId and orgId for document record Id and internal org id):

```
String imageURL = 'https://c.instance.my.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=documentId&oid=orgId'
String htmlImageBodyAttachment = '<center><image id="tellogo" src="' + imageURL + '"/></center>';
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
//address, subject, ect 
mail.setHtmlBody(htmlImageBodyAttachment);
Messagin.sendEmail(new List<Messagin.SingleEmailMessage>{mail});
```

And it's sending the email but then on inspect my `img` tag looks like:

[image]

And if I change the "blockedimagesrc" via inspector for a "src" it displays the image properly.

The image document has access for external users granted and also is available for its use.

**How can I fix this?**

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why not use email template?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal We have an email template with a custom letterhead that has this document but it never displays so that's why I'm triying this kind of approach.

Comment: Check with your IT department, email provider, email client, and/or anti-virus software. I'm guessing that the images are being blocked somewhere downstream from Salesforce. Try using a gmail account or something to test with.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks! I'll check all that today with IT team and post the results.

Comment: @sfdcfox Hi, I check with IT team and it was caused because of the email-provider that authomatically blocked the images from our site. Now it's fixed and working fine. Thanks a lot!